# Set regex for only 2 decimal numbers + dot + comma with jquery validator plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I use [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org) to perform client side form validation. It works well. However, I don't know precisely Regex and I'm not able to achieve what I want.

I would like to add 3 different Regex in order to display 3 different messages depending on what the user enter in input field.:

- Regex 1 detect if it is not a number with a specific message
- Regex 2 accept dot or comma for decimal with a specific message
- only 2 numbers for decimal after dot or comma with a specific message

There are plenty of questions related but I've tried a lot of answers on SO which don't work well.

Here is a working snippet

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("decimal", function(value, element) {
  // Validating Decimal Numbers
  return this.optional(element) || /^([0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|[0-9]+)$/g.test(value);
}, 'Please enter only numbers (format 0.00)');

jQuery.validator.addMethod("two_decimal", function(value, element) {
  // require 2 decimals
  return this.optional(element) || /^((\d+(\\.\d{0,2})?)|((\d*(\.\d{1,2}))))$/.test(value);
}, "Pleaser enter 2 numbers after dot");

// https://jqueryvalidation.org
$("#test_form").validate({

  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  },
  // rules, options, etc.,
  onkeyup: function(element) {
    // "eager" validation
    this.element(element);
  },
  rules: {
    decimal_number: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 10,
      decimal: true,
      two_decimal: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    montant_demande: {
      required: "Please enter a number",
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form class="cmxform" id="test_form" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Test</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="decimal_number">Number decimal</label>
      <input id="decimal_number" name="decimal_number" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `^\d+(?:[.,]\d{1,2})?$` would do it.

Comment: do you want always to have nmber with dot/coma and 2 decimal, or it's a case when typing coma , or number without decimal or number decimal with 2 after dot

Comment: @Spring it's a case when typing coma without decimal, or number with only or more that 2 decimal. User can also enter an integer.

Comment: I would combine the regex into one method/rule rather than trying to make one field follow two different regex rules.

Comment: @Sparky If you combine the regex into one method/rule,  how do you display different messages based on these different cases ?

Comment: @Sparky It could be fine with only one message (I use to do that), but this time, I want to improve ergonomy of my forms. I mostly know PHP, JS, HTML and not very well Regex. That's why I ask for some help to finish.

Comment: As you can see in the accepted answer, one method can have two different messages.

Comment: @Sparky You are absolutely right. That's the key to solve the problem  I was too focused to understand the Regex in the answer and I answer to you too quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only number , or decimal with coma `,` and dot `.` separator with only two decimals ,

See below snippet :

```js
let decimalMessage = "";

jQuery.validator.addMethod("decimal", function(value, element) {
  let decimal = /[^0-9.,]/g.test(value);
  let decimalWithTwoDecimalNumber = /^\d+([.,]\d{2})?$/.test(value);
  
    
  if(decimal) {
    decimalMessage = 'Please enter only numbers (format 0.00)'
    return this.optional(element);
  }
  if(decimalWithTwoDecimalNumber )
    decimalMessage = 'Pleaser enter 2 numbers after dot'
  
  return this.optional(element)||decimalWithTwoDecimalNumber 
},function(params, element) {
    return decimalMessage
});



// https://jqueryvalidation.org
$("#test_form").validate({

  submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit();
  },
  // rules, options, etc.,
  onkeyup: function(element) {
    // "eager" validation
    this.element(element);
  },
  rules: {
    decimal_number: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 1,
      maxlength: 10,
      decimal: true,
    }
  },
  messages: {
    montant_demande: {
      required: "Please enter a number",
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form class="cmxform" id="test_form" method="get" action="">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Test</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="decimal_number">Number decimal</label>
      <input id="decimal_number" name="decimal_number" minlength="2" type="text" required>
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: It's almost ok. I see the case where there are more than 2 numbers after dot/comma  (ex : 50.455) where the message should be "Pleaser enter 2 numbers after dot"

Comment: Okey took me too mush time , but I to only one method with dynamic message check it now :)